# How to hide php extension with a one-line code in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, hide, file-extension

What I wanna ask is, instead of writing many lines into .htaccess including all pages to hide their extensions like

```
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
RewriteRule ^register$ register.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [L]
RewriteRule ^dashboard$ dashboard.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout$ logout.php [L]
```

is there any single line code which will do the same?

Comment: Hi Laurenz Albe, what is your change in my question? You only removed the 'Thank you in advance.' text? Was it necessary to delete that part? I'm asking just to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```